# Cannot access the local farm -Error while running PowerShell Script on Remote Server in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to run a SP PowerShell script remotely from my SP 2013 dev server.The target server is also a SP 2013 server with same configuration.
I am able to get the folders, items, accessing the file system after enabling `Enter-PSSession` command. But when I try to connect the site in the remote server am getting the  below error.

```
[remoteserver1Name]: PS C:\Users\muser1\Documents> $msite=Get-SPSite "http://mydms.prod.com/sites/gng"
```

> Get-SPSite : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to 
>   access the database before trying again.
>   At line:1 char:8
>   + $msite=Get-SPSite "http://mydms.prod.com/sites/gng"

Am stuck at this, why I am getting cannot access local farm?

I am running the SP script with the same credential which has full access to the remote server machine.

Comment: @SaMoIPP p Does that user has permissions on the content DB?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes, it has Full Access to the content db. I went to the security folder in the SSMS console on the  sql server box and given the permissions.It has dbcreator,diskadmin,processadmin,public,securityadmin,serveradmin,setupadmin,sysadmin permissions

Comment: i have followed the blog : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2010/06/10/configure-power-shell-for-remote-use-of-sp-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the -Credential parameter with Kerberos or a username and password. This way, you authenticate with the remote server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx

Comment: I already passed the credential param .but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You also need SPShellAdmin for running PS against the Farm.

[Link here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/add-spshelladmin?view=sharepoint-ps)
also verify that you are in SharePoint Farm Administration group and have permissions set in SQL instance for ConfigDB.